# Default Billing Address not saved when user having no address and do checkout In Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, customer, shipping-address, billing-address

I need help to save the default shipping address as Default Billing address.

Steps to follow :

1. Register as a new customer
2. Now add product into cart
3. Go to Checkout and fill Shipping Address
4. Place an Order
5. Go to Customer Address Book Address is saved as **Default Shipping Address** only.

I need to assign this Default Shipping Address to Default Billing Address.
In **Magento 1.9** if you follow above steps address will be saved as **Default Billing** as well as **Default Shipping.**